# Jquery select clicked element within a set of elements with the same classname

Tags: jquery, class, selector, this

Maybe you guys can help me out with this, I've been struggling with it for the past 30 minutes.

Let's say I have four elements with the same class.

```
<div class="test">hi</div>
<div class="test">hey</div>
<div class="test">yo</div>
<div class="test">What's up</div>
```

How can I select the one that was clicked on?

I was able to get it work like this:

```
$('.test').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("btn-danger btn-success");
});
```

However, I need it to fire without being clicked on success after an ajax call, so I need to be able to do something like this (failed attempts):

```
$('.test', this).toggleClass("btn-danger btn-success"); // This did not work

$(this).find('.test').toggleClass("btn-danger btn-success");  // Also did not work
```

Any suggestions?  Thanks so much!!

Comment: How do you determine which link should have  the event triggered?

Comment: I had a similar problem earlier that I solved by `var self = this`. Perhaps it may help you.

Comment: How do you know which element you need to click after ajax?? Or is the ajax call tied to the click event, which if so, makes it a whole lot easier

Comment: Am I right in thinking that the AJAX call is going to be made by clicking the div? If not, you will need to label them in some other fashion, like by a unique ID or class.

Comment: When I click the element an onclick event triggers the ajax, and then on success I need to select and edit the original element that was clicked that triggered the ajax call.  I still have no idea how to do this.  Thanks for the help so far though.

Comment: Just so everyone knows, I ended up doing this with the onclick method rather than with data-param html attributes as my parameters.  What you have to do in order to access this is to set $(this) as a parameter in the onclick attribute, and use that parameter to select this within the ajax call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like the ajax call is made when one of the elements is clicked, but you need to pass different values in the ajax call depending on which element is clicked. Rather than use an "onclick" attribute, you could do the following:

HTML:

```
<div class="test" data-param1="value1a" data-param2="value2a">hi</div>
<div class="test" data-param1="value1b" data-param2="value2b">hey</div>
<div class="test" data-param1="value1c" data-param2="value2c">yo</div>
<div class="test" data-param1="value1d" data-param2="value2d">What's up</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.test').click(function() {
    var $div = $(this);
    $.ajax(url, {
        data: {
            param1: $div.attr('data-param1'),
            param2: $div.attr('data-param2')
        },
        success: function() {
            $div.toggleClass("btn-danger btn-success");
        }
    });
});
```

Of course, you would set the values of the `data-` attributes using PHP variables.

Comment: This worked for me.  The only reason I couldn't use this method before is that I did not know about passing variables to my ajax function like described here. :)  Much thanks I fixed my code!

Answer (score 1):

Use the trigger function....

So attach the click handler...

```
$('.test').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("btn-danger btn-success");
});
```

Then in your ajax success function....trigger that click...

```
$('.test').trigger('click');
```

But determining which one to trigger will be the trick.

How do you know which one to click, based on the ajax????

If you're just doing an ajax call, based on which link you cick then the solution is much simpler.......cuz you already know which link was clicked

```
$('.test').click(function() {
var link = $(this);
$.ajax(url, {
    success: function() {
        link.toggleClass("btn-danger btn-success");
     }
   });
});
```

Comment: This seems promising, i'm going to play around with this, thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution will not work for me because I can't trigger the ajax call with $('.test').click(function() { I have to call it with the onclick method because i'm passing in dynamic php variables as parameters for the ajax function.

Comment: If you just post what you mean....I can help you....cuz Im sure trigger is exactly what you need

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('.test').click(function(){
   clicked = $(this);
 });
```

The above code returns an array of a single item. So use index 0 to select it as below:

```
$('.test').click(function(){
  clicked = $(this)[0];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it not possible to give each of these an ID so you can access them directly?

If you are triggering them on a callback function can you create a reference to the clicked div in a variable?

i.e.

```
 var clicked;

 $('.test').click(function(){
     clicked = $(this);
 });
```

then in your ajax response:

```
 clicked.toggleClass("btn-danger btn-success");
```

Comment: This will not work for me, because the ajax call is triggered on the div's onclick.  I have to use onclick because it passes php array's that are being looped.