# jQuery Seperate the divs with selected one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple divs with same div ids but i want to separate each div when any main div gets activate it will show its sub div, I tried many functions but nothing works for me. here is my code

css

```
.active{
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:black;
}
```

JS

```
    $('div[id^="show"]').hide();
    $("div").click(function(){
    $('div').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
        setTimeout(function(){
                $('div[id^="show"]').show();
            setTimeout(function() {
        $('div[id^="show"]').hide()
    }, 5000);
        }, 3000);
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="div">
content 1
<div id="show">ad here1</div>
</div>
<div class="div">
content 2
<div id="show">ad here2</div>
</div>
<div class="div">
content 3
<div id="show">ad here3</div>
</div>
<div class="div">
content 4
<div id="show">ad here4</div>
</div>
```

What I actually want is, when someone clicks on parent div having text "content 1" its child div having id  "show" will appear and close instead of all divs with id "show"

Comment: First of all,using multiples id is not valid, it is not good to use can make problems, use classes

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery select clicked element within a set of elements with the same classname](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254118/jquery-select-clicked-element-within-a-set-of-elements-with-the-same-classname)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the output hope it will help, i have omitted timeouts, you can insert them again

- You need to find the div with id show in the clicked div
- then hide the other divs with id as show and filter out its own child with show as id using not()
- use class instead of id for #show , correct it

```js
$('div#show').hide();
$("div").click(function() {
  $('div').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  
    $neardiv = $(this).find('div#show');
    $neardiv.show();
   
      $('div#show').not($neardiv).hide()
    

});
```

```css
.active {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: black;
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class="div">
  content 1
  <div id="show">ad here1</div>
</div>
<div class="div">
  content 2
  <div id="show">ad here2</div>
</div>
<div class="div">
  content 3
  <div id="show">ad here3</div>
</div>
<div class="div">
  content 4
  <div id="show">ad here4</div>
</div>
```